# Hashed password with JAX and JPA

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, jaxb, jax-rs

I have a User class with a password field and the following property annotated with JAXB and JPA:

```
@Column(name = "PASSWORD")
@XmlElement(name = "Password")
public String getPasswordHash() {
    return passwordHash;
}

public void setPasswordHash(String passwordHash) {
    try {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        this.passwordHash = (new HexBinaryAdapter()).marshal(md.digest(passwordHash.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))));
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(User.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

I am expecting a password that is created with a POST method using JAX-RS being put into the database as a hashed string. Instead the value written to the database is a hashed-hashed String. For instance when the password is `"Password"` than the database value is set to `"7FDB74C6E3A8EC7E6B55F83D20FFE116"`

Which evaluates as:

1. `MD5("Password") = "DC647EB65E6711E155375218212B3964"`
2. `MD5("DC647EB65E6711E155375218212B3964") = "7FDB74C6E3A8EC7E6B55F83D20FFE116"`

Even stranger, when I do a GET using JAX-RS, which returns a list of all Users, the passwords in the database are all updated and hashed again every time I do a GET. The controller method for the GET is pretty straightforward:

```
public List<T> findAll() throws EJBAccessException, Exception {
    CriteriaQuery cq = em.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
    cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
    return em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
}
```

And the boundery method is straightforward too:

```
@GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Response get() {
    try {
        List<T> entities = getController().findAll();
        return Response.ok(new GenericEntity(entities, getType())).build();
    } catch (EJBAccessException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(entityClass.getName())
                .log(Level.INFO, ex.getMessage());
        return Response.status(Response.Status.FORBIDDEN)
                .entity(ex.getMessage()).build();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(entityClass.getName())
                .log(Level.WARNING, ex.getMessage());
        return Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                .entity(ex.getMessage()).build();
    }
}
```

Why are the passwords double hashed when I put them into the database? Why are passwords using a GET rehashed?

I am using WildFly 8.2 as my Java EE 7 container running on Java SE 8. (RestEasy and Hibernate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ques 1 : It seems your password are getting hashed once by your JSON serializer and then by persistence layer as the hashing is implemented in setter.

Ques 2: Regarding GET operation, when you retrieve data from database the setter is called and the returned entity is `Persistent` and "dirty"(as password value has changed) so, at end of the transaction `entitymanager` flushes all dirty objects to database.

Ideally as uaiHebert has already suggested move the hashing out of the setter method.

Comment: Why does the entitymanager flush the dirty objects when EnityManager.persist() is not called??

Comment: This is JPA behaviour, read [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-overview).

Comment: So if I understand correctly, when I call `em.createQuery(cq).getResultList()` the `return` object gets the persistent state, after which JPA checks for changes between the database and the object and updates the database because `getPasswordHash()` has a different value than the `passwordHash` in the object?

Comment: yes correct. If you move the hashing impl from the setter, this problem should be solved as well.

Answer (score -2):

Any framework could invoke the setMethod, maybe when you get from database or when you convert the value to JSON.

I would do it outside the class or you will need to create other method to do the encrypt of the password.

Comment: Sorry but 'any framework could invoke the setMethod' is not good enough. Which framework? At what call? Why?
I would agree with your workaround, to do it in the controller, but then I need to override all controller methods (get, post, put, delete), which I prefer not to do. And it would be a workaround for a problem I don't fully understand.